# Post title not rendering in jekyll blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jekyll

I'm using jekyll and https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy within my rails application, and I'm trying to add post titles to my post.html layout. I can't seem to get the title to render, even after trying `{{ post.title }}` and `{{ title }}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using `{{ page.title }}` did the trick!